# Proving two Sets are Equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is a subset of the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bijective function. We use the notation $gAg^{−1}={g∘f∘g^{−1}:f∈A}$. Prove that $A≈gAg^{−1}$.

I know to show equivalence I need to show a bijection from $A$ to $gAg^{−1}$.

I think I start with an element of $A$, and then find a surjective function?

Comment: What does ≈ mean in this context?  $A=gAg^{-1}$ exactly when $A$ is a normal subgroup of the set of all functions, under the operation composition.

Comment: Do you just need to show they have the same number of elements? In that case you already have the function you need, you just need to show it's a bijection.

Comment: Yes, I believe I only need to show that gAg^{-1} is a bijection, but I'm not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi_g$ be the function from $X$ to $X$ ($X$ being the set of function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) which associates to $f$ the function defined by $g\circ f\circ g^{-1}$.

Then $\phi_g\circ\phi_{g^{-1}}=Id_X=\phi_{g^{-1}}\circ\phi_g$. Furthermore $\phi_g(A)=gAg^{-1}$ and $\phi_{g^{-1}}(gAg^{-1})=A$.

Then you have a bijection between $A$ and $gAg^{-1}$.